# VMware Fusion black screen on boot

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-fusion

I'm having this issue with VMware Fusion recently when I try to start metasploitable 2 virtual machine which is basically Ubuntu. So once I click on "start up" button I get a solid black screen and that's it nothing else happens. I do not even get the VMware BIOS screen. Things I tried to resolve this issue are:

- Deleted the virtual machine and reinstalled it.
- Removed VMware and reinstalled it.
- Unchecked the "Accelerate 3D Graphic" box.
- Checked the intel VT-x/EPT box.

The virtual machine specification are:

- 1 processor.
- 512 MB of RAM.

The VMware Fusion is Professional Version 8.5.6 running on MacBook Pro 2016 model with the latest update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had exactly the same problem, and it turns out it is introduced with the update to macOS Sierra 10.12.4.

The solution to this problem is to open the .vmx file of the virtual machine, and add the following line to it:

```
mks.enableGLBasicRenderer = "FALSE"
```

It fully resolved the issue on my end. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. you are a lifesaver, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have an ongoing problem similar to this.  VMWare Fusion gets a blank screen when its been in the background for a while (possibly Windows has gone to sleep).  Clicking on the window, suspending & resuming doesn't do anything.

I have found the sending Ctrl-Alt-Del from the Virtual Machine menu brings the VM back to life rather than hard rebooting the VM and possibly losing data.